# VsCode VIM - How to open "New Untitled File"

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, vim-plugin, vsvim

In VsCode VIM (vanilla installation), how would you execute <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>? When inspecting the keyboard shortcut, it looks like this:

[image]

I tried the plain way in VIM by running `:new`, but it opened a new tab within the same editor instead of a whole new tab.

Ideally, I'm looking for a plain way to do this without having to re-map any keys. I'm a big proponent of using vanilla tooling so I can easily transfer machine without having to carry around my re-mappings.

Comment: Perhaps :enew is what youre after

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That was the answer. You should post it and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In vim, I use `:enew` to start a brand new file.

Comment: The only thing that sucks is it doesn't work if you're in the default "Welcome" screen.

Answer (score 9):

You can try `:e`

Example

```
:e test.js
```

Or install extension like this : https://github.com/dkundel/vscode-new-file

Comment: This isn't a great answer. A plugin shouldn't be required to open a new file in my opinion.

Comment: Great, `:e` works for me. `:enew` gives me a E488 error.

Answer (score 1):

In **--NORMAL--** 
`:e` or `:enew` then press `enter`. 
This will create new and open a new file tap.